# Show existing activity from AppWidget click

Tags: android, android-activity, android-appwidget

I have a problem opening an activity from an appwidget. I have tried different Intent flags, PendingIntent and launch modes without any luck. I have read diffent examples here and many other places without finding the solution.

Right now when I click my button on my appwidget it opens a new activity instead of showing the instance which already exists in the app. I have posted my code below and hope you can help me.

Is there a way to find the existing activity and show it instead of creating a new one when clicking my bottom on the appwidget?

Manifest:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true" android:name="widget.helper.ResourceHelper">
    <activity android:name=".ScoreBoard"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />                                
        </intent-filter>         
    </activity>


    <!-- Broadcast Receiver that will process AppWidget updates -->
    <receiver android:name="Widget" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" android:resource="@xml/widget_provider" />
    </receiver>     
</application>
```

The AppWidget:

```
public class Widget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        RemoteViews remoteViews;
        ComponentName thisWidget;
        remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
        thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, Widget.class);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);
    }

    @Override    
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    { 
        super.onReceive(context, intent);

        if(intent.getAction().equals("OPEN_APP")) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            i.setComponent(new ComponentName("widget","widget.ScoreBoard"));
            ResourceHelper.getScoreBoard().startActivity(i);
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the activity launchMode to singleInstance in manifest.

Let us know if it is working.

Saneesh

Answer (score 0):

Use either `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` or the *combination* of `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` *and* `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`. `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` without `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` would not work, AFAIK.